# Can I start a Microdata after <head> and end the same just before </body>?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

1. I want to use itemscope Website. Can I start it just after `<head>` and end it just before `</body>`?
2. For Website itemscope, which itemprop should I use to define the logo for the Website?

Comment: You mean not in the _head_ section but in the _body_, as covered [here](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html), right?

Comment: These two questions don’t seem to be related. I’d suggest to remove the second question and create a separate question post for it, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the `WebSite` itemscope, a perfectly viable alternative would be to use JSON-LD format as opposed to Microdata, namely because the scope of a `Website` would include the `<head>` element as well.

To put that into context, the `name` item property of the `WebPage` element is best represented with the `<title>` element, which lives in the head of the document.

`WebSite`, which structurally should be the parent of `WebPage` (which is what all pages are be default) would be difficult to place properly using the normal DOM markup of the page.

This is why this JSON-LD is preferred for this particular form of markup to avoid create any scope problems and accidentally 'breaking' the structured data of your webpage.

Here is a sample snippet to handle most cases for the Website element:

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
   "@type" : "WebSite",
   "name" : "Example",
   "alternateName" : "e.g.",
   "url" : "http://example.com",
   "image": "http://example.com/logo.png",
   "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "http://example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
      "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    }
}
```

Now, I would actually advise *against* using logo for the `WebSite` property, and would prefer if you did it either as a child of `WebPage` or better yet use the appropriate Schema.org i.e. `ProfessionalService`, `LocalBusiness` etc to define the logo and simple use `mainEntity` to define your root domain to be the main entity of that property.

This is so that the `logo` of your `ProfessionalService`, `CrativeWork`, `LocalBusiness` or whatever child is appropriate is also the `logo` for your website by the nature of good relations as opposed to an explicit definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the `itemscope` on the `<head>` tag, the Microdata item "ends" with the `</head>` tag.

If you want to add properties from the `head` as well as from the `body`, you have three options:

- specify the `itemscope` on the `html` element
- specify the `itemscope` only on one of these and use the `itemref` attribute to reference properties from the other one
- specify two items (one on the `head` and one on the `body`) and use the same `itemid` value to denote that these are about the same thing

Answer (score -3):

No need for manual coding for it.

Just log in to Webmaster Tools,

Navigate through Search Appearance -> Data Highlighter -> Start Highlighting

Comment: But "Type of the information to highlight" doesn't have what I wish to have/what my Website is about. So in this case we must I should write manual code only, right? Or do I have any other alternative?

Comment: This would only help Google, while using markup would help all interested consumers.